# How to turn on AOT in an angular hybrid application using downgradeModule and angular-cli?

Tags: angularjs, angular, aot, angular-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I am migrating an AngularJS application to Angular 7 using the downgradeModule (described here: [upgrade for performance](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade-performance)). In the last part of that documentation it is stated that I need to import the NgModuleFactory of my AppModule when I want to use AOT. I am using the angular-cli for building the application. Is it possible to reference the ModuleFactory that is created in the angular-cli build and therefore turn on AOT for my hybrid app?